# Why can't I publish my AIML chatbot on Pandorabots?

Tags: aiml, pandorabots

I have a created a chatbot on Pandorabots and have paid the money to get an API.  I've been programming the bot and accessing it from my application with no problems for about 2 weeks.

Today I made some edits to my chatbot files, and the changes work just fine in the widget on the Pandorabots page.  However, when I try to click Publish Changes, my cursor turned into a circle-slash symbol and the changes do not go through. If I click Publish Changes in the sidebar, the option just disappears. I am not anywhere near my message limit.  My credit card info looks good.  I have searched everywhere, but can't find any info or anyone to talk to about it.

I am supposed to give a demo tomorrow for about 100 people, and right now I can't make it behave how I want it to ... would really appreciate some advice!

Comment: What colour is the circle next to your bot, green or yellow? Have you tried logging out and back in again?

Comment: I have logged out and back in again several times.  Always, when I first login I have a regular cursor when I click on Publish Changes, but when I click on it the first time, it pauses for a moment, then turns into the circle-slash and I can't click again.

The circle is doing its normal thing, turning to yellow when I make changes and then green when I save them.  My changes show up in the widget, but don't make it to my API.

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Have you contacted support@pandorabots.com ?

Comment: I haven't ... but I will right now